# Prepopulate values in lightning record form lwc

Tags: lightning, lwc-wire-adapter, lightning-web-components, lwc-dev-server

I’m trying to create one lwc component, where I need to prepopulate some values including lookup in lightning-record-form. Is it possible to do this in lwc?

Answer (score 2):

The following is a discussion on this subject from the Partner forums that I started:

> I am writing a custom LWC, one aspect of which is the ability to create a new record based on the context of that custom LWC instance. The LWC component holds the ID of a parent object. The child (to be created) has a Master Detail relationship back to the parent.
>
> When my component creates the new (child) record, I want to use lightning-record-form. The reason is that I want the form to include all fields that the admin has populated into the full layout - my LWC component is part of a package and I cannot make any assumption about the fields that should or should not be in the form over and above the master details field. Use of the lightning-record-edit-form therefore doesn't make sense (since I would have to explicitly define the list of fields to be shown and I can't).
>
> I am trying to work out how to use the parent ID from the LWC component to pre-populate the Master Details field in the new record, but all my research leads me to the answer that I cannot.
>
> There is an event, "load", generated by the lightning-record-form component, and this provides access to the record data. However, according to what I've read on Stack Exchange, setting the field values in here does NOT cause the form to update its Master Detail field.
>
> There is another event, "submit", generated when the user tries to save the new record, and according to the documentation (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation, in the "Editing a Record" section) this event can intercept the data to explicitly override values for certain fields. However, since I'm trying to set what is effectively a mandatory field, I suspect my submit handler won't be invoked before the form decides it is missing a mandatory value.
>
> Has anyone actually got this working? How did you do it?

Commenter:

> We faced this challenge (a little more generically -- we just wanted to be able to populate a few fields, at our choosing, before loading the lightning-record-form)
>
> We raised it to (Salesforce) who confirmed that this is indeed 'working as designed' and no concrete timelines were offered for allowing the caller to specify defaults :-(

Response from Salesforce:

> I completely understand -- however, record-form was designed to be an out-of-the-box easy way to do a form that *doesn't* need any special handling.
>
> I'm looking into other possibilities, but don't currently have a timeline.

**And so the answer:**

The upshot is that this component doesn't support pre-populating fields in the form. There are alternatives to this, if you don't mind the form being opened in a separate tab. The approach we used was to adopt Doug Ayers' Aura-based mechanism as described [here](https://douglascayers.com/2018/08/05/legitimate-url-hacking-in-lightning-experience/).

**UPDATE**: Based on Avi Rai's answer, I see the NavigationMixin now allows setting of default field values as described in the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_lc_navigate_to_record_dfv.htm) so if you are OK to use Spring '20 that's a way forward without using Doug Ayer's mechanism. It doesn't work with communities.

Answer (score 2):

There is an onload method in Record Form which we have to override
Something like this

```
this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field').forEach(i=>{
            if(i.fieldName == 'fieldApiName'){
                i.value = 'Test';
            }
});
```

Answer (score -4):

With Spring'20 you can now provide the default fields values to the create record form using navigation service.

Please have a look to below link which describes your requirement and answer properly - https://livingthetrailhead.com/2020/01/12/navigate-to-a-records/

Comment: Nice. I would suggest providing a link to the release notes instead of your own blog posting in the first place. I added such a link to my answer for clarification. Thanks for pointing this out!